# jQuery AJAX Response is incorrect on the second try

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a C# .NET Core project using Razor partial view and jQuery.

I am making a jQuery AJAX request as per the below, which hits the API to return data to load into a Modal.

```
$(document).on('click', '.editmodal', function () {
        var optionnumber = $(this).attr('number');
        document.getElementById("EditOption").value = optionnumber;
        var form = document.getElementById('race');
        var formData = new FormData(form);

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ViewEditRaceOption", "Races")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'html',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
            if (response) {  // check if data is defined
                $("#optionmodal").html(response);
                console.log(response)
            }
            }

    });

        document.getElementById("EditOption").value = 0;
        $('#optionsmodal').modal('show');
    });
```

The first time this executes, it runs just fine. Te response in the Network tab returns the HTML and loads it into the page.

However the second time, the response is wrong as it has has not replaced my form values. It’s as if the model hasn’t bound to the view.

The controller looks like this.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ViewEditRaceOption(RaceViewModel race)
        {
            var vm = race;
            var option = race.RaceOptionData.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Number == race.EditOption);
            vm.OptionAffiliatedDiscountValue = option.AffiliatedDiscountValue;
            vm.OptionColour = option.OptionColour;
            vm.OptionEmbedMapURL = option.EmbedMapURL;
            vm.OptionEntryPremium = option.Premium;
            vm.OptionEntryPrice= option.AffiliatedDiscountValue;
            vm.OptionMaxEntries= option.MaxEntries;
            vm.OptionName= option.Name;
            vm.OptionRaceDistance = option.RaceDistance;
            vm.OptionStartTime = option.StartTime;
            vm.OptionCertificateFileName = option.CourseMeasurementCertificateFileName;
            return PartialView("OptionModal", vm);
        }
```

Putting a break point on the `Return` line shows that the data is correct in the returned model.

The partial view looks like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label value="OptionName" class="control-label">Option Name</label>
            <br /><small class="text-muted">The name of this Race Option</small>
            <input asp-for="OptionName" placeholder="Your 10k" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Name">
            <span asp-validation-for="OptionName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label name="OptionRaceDistance" value="Race Distance" class="control-label">Distance</label>
            <br /><small class="text-muted">Choose a race distance, used for Age Grading </small>

            <select asp-for="OptionRaceDistance" required class="form-control">
                <option value="" selected>--select--</option>
                <option value="M1">1 mile</option>
                <option value="KM5">5 km</option>
                <option value="KM6">6 km</option>
                <option value="M4">4 miles</option>
                <option value="KM8">8 km</option>
                <option value="M5">5 miles</option>
                <option value="KM10">10 km</option>
                <option value="KM12">12 km</option>
                <option value="KM15">15 km</option>
                <option value="M10">10 miles</option>
                <option value="KM20">20 km</option>
                <option value="Half">Half Marathon</option>
                <option value="KM25">25 km</option>
                <option value="KM30">30 km</option>
                <option value="Marathon">Marathon</option>
                <option value="KM50">50 km</option>
                <option value="M50">50 miles</option>
                <option value="KM100">100 km</option>
                <option value="KM150">150 km</option>
                <option value="M100">100 miles</option>
                <option value="KM200">200 km</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select><br />
            <span asp-validation-for="OptionRaceDistance" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label name="OptionMaxEntries" value="Maximum Entries" class="control-label">Maximum Entries</label>
            <br /><small class="text-muted">The maximum capacity of the race</small>


            <input asp-for="OptionMaxEntries" class="form-control" type="number" />
            <span asp-validation-for="OptionMaxEntries" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label name="OptionStartTime" value="Start Time" class="control-label">Race Start Time</label>
            <br /><small class="text-muted">Start time in HH:MM</small>
            <input asp-for="OptionStartTime" value="19:00" asp-format="{0:hh:mm}" class="form-control" type="time" />
            <span asp-validation-for="OptionStartTime" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Colour</label>
            <br /><small class="text-muted">Choose the colour for this option. </small>
            <select asp-for="OptionColour" class="form-control">
                <option value="White" selected>White</option>
                <option value="Red">Red</option>
                <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
                <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
                <option value="Green">Green</option>
                <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
            </select><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Course Measurement Certificate</label>
            <br /><small class="text-muted">PDF file of certificate for this race option</small>
            <input asp-for="OptionCourseMeasurementCertificateFile" type="file" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="OptionCourseMeasurementCertificateFile" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Course Map URL</label>
            <br /><small class="text-muted">Provide a URL to a Garmin, Strava or other course mapping tool</small>
            <input asp-for="OptionEmbedMapURL" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="OptionEmbedMapURL" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




@if (Model.RaceData.CanBePremium)
                    {
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input asp-for="OptionEntryPremium" /> Premium Race Option
                    <br /><small class="text-muted">This is a premium race option and will cost @Model.BaseCurrency.Symbol@Model.BaseFee.ToString("0.00") per race entry</small>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label value="OptionEntryPrice" class="control-label">Entry Price</label>
            <br /><small class="text-muted">The price of the normal race entry</small>
            <input asp-for="OptionEntryPrice" type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount" placeholder="10.00" asp-format="{0:0.00}" >
            <span asp-validation-for="OptionEntryPrice" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Affiliation Discount</label>
            <br /><small class="text-muted">Value of discount for affiliation</small>
            <input asp-for="OptionAffiliatedDiscountValue" type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount" value="2.00" asp-format="{0:0.00}" >
            <span asp-validation-for="OptionAffiliatedDiscountValue" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

                    }
```

Additionally, the button pressed is itself dynamically generated in a partial view in case that is helpful information

Any ideas why this is?  I'd like the button pressed to execute and get the right response every time.

Comment: In what way is the response wrong?

Comment: no doubt a question of cache, we must add the good header on the return of ajax

Comment: Has not replaced the form values Patrick - all just defaults like the model hasn’t bound to the view.

Comment: I don’t think it is cache Mister Jojo as the second response is different to the first

Comment: A little off topic here, but is there a reason your are not using [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)?

Comment: It’s my first time with Ajax and the examples I have been reading up on all tended to recommend .on at document level as the button executing the Post is dynamic. Does .load bring a benefit?

Comment: I meant how does the wrong response differ from the "right" response? For instance if the right response was the string "yes" a wrong response would be "42". So what was the wrong response in your case? Did get the right html structure but get wrong values in the various elements? Or did you just mean your html wasnt updated(which isnt a wrong response simply a failure for the code to update the elements on the page)

Comment: @Patrick - the "wrong" response is non-parsed template language returned as HTML while the "right" response is HTML parsed (interpolated) template.

Comment: @Matthew - the benefit of `load()` is that this is the entire AJAX request plus the insertion of the response into the DOM: `$("#optionmodal").load('@Url.Action(ViewEditRaceOption", "Races"')`

Comment: @Patrick The controller responds with an HTML template and a data model. The first time the request is executed the final returned HTML that console.log shows includes the values from the data model in the input field values. The second time around the HTML does not have the data model properties included in the input field values.

Comment: @Randy i’ll give .load a try and see if it helps